# How to use regular expression to add plus 1 in the middle of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I had `name_1` and could easily do a regex to make `name_2`, `name_3`.

My problem is that now I have, `name_1'english`, `name_1'portuguese`.

This is the code I had:

```
the_string.replace(/_\d+$/, '_'+(1))
```

And of course, this worked great for the first need, but now I can't. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a callback with `replace`:

```
the_string = the_string.replace(/_(\d+)/, function(m, c0) {
    return "_" + (+c0 + 1);
});
```

There, I'm using a capture group for the matched digits, which is passed to the function as the second argument, so I'm returning that converted to a number plus one (with a `_` in front of it).

Example:

```js
var the_string = "name_1'en";
the_string = the_string.replace(/_(\d+)/, function(m, c0) {
  return "_" + (+c0 + 1);
});
snippet.log(the_string);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whoever recently upvoted Christoph's comment: That hasn't been true since just *before* he commented. Note the `+` before `c0`. There's no need for `parseInt` when you know you have all digits (as we do above).